# Update problem with listbox form fed from a query

Tags: ms-access

I am feeding a listbox in my form with a query result that depend on other controls of the same form. The problem is that my listbox doesn't update wheareas when I launch the query manually, the result is good.

Comment: Have you tried requerying the listbox in VBA in the afterupdate events of the various controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Remou suggests put Me.listBox.Requery in the AfterUpdate event of the control it is depending on:

```
  Private Sub yourDataSourceUIElement_AfterUpdate()
      yourListBox.Requery
  End Sub
```

Comment: It's bad practice to not qualify your control references. Either `Me.yourListBox.Requery` or `Me!yourListBox.Requery` (my preference) is better, as it makes clear what is being referred to (and doesn't leave it up to the compiler to figure it out on its own).